# Evaluate a indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to look for $\int \frac{1}{\ln x}\ dx$? I wonder if this form of integral could ever have an analytical solution? If not, why?

I've tried substitution with $u=\ln x$. So, $du=\frac{1}{x}\ dx$ and the original integral is equivalent to $\int \frac{e^u}{u}du$. But I'm unable to proceed further from here. Hope somebody could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no closed form solution to this integral. All you can do is to solve it using Taylor series.

Comment: So, how can one know that there's no closed form for any integral? Just generally speaking, is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: I said it because of experience....actually i don't have any idea with this but i found a link in Wikipedia that may help.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is also called the [logarithmic integral function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function) denoted by $\operatorname {li}(x) $ and is defined by: $$\operatorname {li}(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac {\mathrm dt }{\ln t} $$